# The opposite of "far ago"?

Tags: idioms, expressions, idiomatic-language

While I was having a conversation, I used "far later" to mean "far in the future" but I didn't feel like this is a common expression. Is there the direct opposite of "far ago" in time?

Comment: It's [non-standard phrasing,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+far+ago%2Cwas+long+ago&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) which is why you won't find any definitions. For the past, it's ***long ago***. For the future you might say *That's **far off** yet*, but the standard intensifier for ***later*** is ***much** later*.

Comment: Can you give more context? How did you use "far later" what was the rest of the sentence (as you remember it)?

Comment: I think *far later* sounds natural, just *later* intensified. But *far ago* sounds strange. The reason may be that "later* is comparative word, but while *ago* is an adjective or adverb, it doesn't seem to be comparable, except with another word: *longer ago*, *far longer ago*.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: ***far later*** is "acceptable", but I can't think of any context where it would actually be *preferred* over ***much later***. Which is [far more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=far+later%2Cmuch+later&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Apparently [***far*** does better with ***more common*** than with ***later***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=far+more+common%2Cmuch+more+common&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is found at Google Books, and in the Google news search. Maybe Its uncommonness makes it sound more intense to me.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: Well, if a native speaker uses a "less common" turn of phrase we generally tend to assume they had a reason, and an obvious candidate is "emphasis". As you say, the mere fact of hearing a "slightly unexpected" turn of phrase, makes it stand out a bit, so "sounding more intense" sorta comes with the territory. Basically, ***far*** goes further than ***much*** because we haven't worn it out through overuse yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the definitions of **far** is *by a great deal*, so it would be possible to say, for example

> We eat our evening meal far later than you do (at a much later time of day).

However, it doesn't sound idiomatic to say *far later* in the context 'a long way into the future'; and *far ago* certainly isn't valid English.